# How to run a program's purpose more than once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Below is my code for a simple dice rolling program and the program itself is fine, but my issue is that once I roll (or don't) I can no longer do any actions aside from killing the program, any and all help is greatly appreciated.

```
import random

inp = input("Do you want to roll? Y/N - ").lower()

if inp=="Y".lower():

    print(random.sample(range(1,6),2))

if inp=="N".lower():

    print("Standing by")

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep the program running, add a loop to the program that will only terminate once the user enters 'n'

```
import random

while True:
    inp = input("Do you want to roll? Y/N - ").lower()

    if inp == "y":
        print(random.sample(range(1,6),2))
        continue # ask again

    if inp == "n":
        print("Standing by")
        break # jump to the last line

input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to ask how to add a loop, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Like AK47 this can also be done with functions.  The whole point of functions is to re-use code

```
import random


def roll():
    print(random.sample(range(1, 6), 2))


while True:
    inp = input("Do you want to roll? Y/N - ").lower()
    if inp == "Y".lower():
        roll()
    elif inp == "N".lower():
        print("Standing by")
    else:
        break
```